# GUI on how to reads a set of numbers in a single textbox control

Tags: java, jframe

In GUI Jframe: how to reads a set of numbers in a single textbox control and calculates the mean?

Comment: You can do it by writing some code.

Comment: Without showing the code you've written yourself and where you got stuck we've got no chance to help you.

Comment: What is a "textbox". I'm not aware of and Swing component with that name.

Answer (score 0):

you can split this numbers and store to ArrayList or Set for further use.

```
String numbers = "22,44,5,95,1";

List<String> numberList = Arrays.asList(numbers.split(","));
```

Comment: Okay I will try but the question here is that how can i use the single "Textbox" to store more than one value, can i use comma "," to separate the value? e.g "22, 44, 5, 95, 1"

Comment: @AhmedBishara yes. I was updated my answer. Please check.